# Fill form with .getJSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, getjson

I want to fill form inputs with JSON encoded data from ajax. My jQuery code is

```
$('#event_id').blur(function(){
    $.getJSON('../ajax/regattaformAjax.php', fetchOld);
    function fetchOld(data){
        $.each(data, function(label, value){
            $('[#'+label+']',data).val(value);
        });
    }
});
```

and the JSON-encoded data from regattaformAjax.php is

`{"Address":"1717 88th Dr SE","Chevrons":"Black","City":"Lake Stevens","Class":"IOM","ClubAMYA#":"132"}`

There are no errors in the console. Where did I go astray?

Comment: can we see the form html ?

Comment: `$('#'+label).val(value);` maybe, depending on the mark up

Comment: Form html for this input: <td style="width:30%;" ><label><input type="radio" name="new_ren" id="renew" value="Renew" /><span style="color: #2D8AB9;font-size:1em; font-weight:bold;">CHANGE REGATTA</ span></label></td>
   <td style="color: #2D8AB9;font-size:1em;"><label id="changeLabel">Regatta ID <input type="text" id="event_id" name="regatta_id" <?php echo $changeClass ?> size="6" /></label></td></tr>

Comment: @musa, thanks but no joy

Comment: Further information: Console shows "Database error:400". Running the server file with a hard-coded query string generates what appears to be valid JSON-formatted data as seen in the original post.

Comment: your selector select nothing! says for example: `$('#Address')` is selecting `<div id="Address"></div>`

Comment: I did not upload the entire HTML to the forum. Rest assured that all ids are in place and match the JSON.